# Using frames from Natcorder Video?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Unity's NatCorder asset to get frames of a video. Is this possible? I can record video using NatCorder using:

```
WebCamTexture webCam;
webCam.Play();
NatCorder.StartRecording(Configuration.Screen, OnVideo);
//Note: OnVideo is a separate function that natcorder calls after taking the video
```

and then in my update function:

```
if (NatCorder.IsRecording && cameraTexture.didUpdateThisFrame) {
    // Acquire an encoder frame from NatCorder
    var frame = NatCorder.AcquireFrame();
    // Blit the current camera preview frame to the encoder frame
    Graphics.Blit(cameraTexture, frame);
    // Commit the frame to NatCorder for encoding
    NatCorder.CommitFrame(frame);
}
```

but my goal is to take each frame and encode it to a png or jpg file instead of creating a video. Is this possible, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please can someone help?